# Downloading tflite models from server rather than using the models from assets folder in Android

Tags: android, tflite

I want to use the tflite models from server，but I can't download them into `assets` folder. So I have to load the model form sd card or other place, and how can I do that? I have tried to load the model directly, but it needs the startOffset and declaredLength of the model, which could get from `AssetFileDescriptor` if the model in asset folder. I don't know how to get them when the model in sd card.

Answer (score 0):

For loading the lite models from  a Server, You can follow [Firebase ML kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/use-custom-models) document along [Lite inference document](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs) (explained in Java/C++/Swift ) to modify your android project accordingly.